NextJS localization always routes to 'en' despite config
I have a project in NextJS where I am using i18n and everything works fine except for when I enter the site where translation is supposed to be in 'sr', but for some reason, Next routes to 'en'. Here's my config file
const i18nConfig = {
  locales: ["sr", "en"],
  defaultLocale: "sr",
  localeDetection: false,
  serverLanguageDetection: false,
  browserLanguageDetection: false,
  domains: [
    {
      domain: "carbooker.rs",
      defaultLocale: "sr",
    },
    {
      domain: "dev.carbooker.rs",
      defaultLocale: "sr",
    },
  ],
};

module.exports = i18nConfig;

